# How can I get the deployed URL that's the domain with Vercel?

Tags: next.js, vercel

Looking at the docs here https://vercel.com/docs/deployments/generated-urls, it seems that `VERCEL_URL` and `NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL` are: `<project-name>-<unique-hash>-<scope-slug>.vercel.app`

How can I get the domain instead of the Unique view of deployment?

Answer (score 1):

If Vercel offered all the domains associated to a production deployment as an environment variable, what would happen when that specific deployment is no longer the one in production?

Environment variables in Vercel should be immutable. Therefore, a dynamic value like a domain cannot be passed on. The unique URL of the deployment is immutable, and that is why it is available. So you either have a list of domains inside your code as a constant or check [HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) for a 'runtime value'. Another option for the client is to use `window` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)). One example using Next.js middleware can be found [here](https://github.com/vercel/platforms/blob/main/middleware.ts#L43-L47).